# Possible to introspect collation on a string in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, collation

Let's say I have the following:

```
SELECT COLLATE("hello", "und:ci")
```

If this string value of `"hello"` is ever used later, for example in a comparison -- or stored to a table that is later accessed, I'd like to inspect its collation. Is there any way to do this from the value-itself (not checking `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`)? For example, I can use the `FORMAT("%T", value)` to inspect the type and get all that information (albeit painfully), is there any way in which I can output a string-value to see whether it has any collation that is bound to it (either inherited from the table, column, function, etc.)?

---

As another example, if I create a Javascript UDF and pass it a string, is there a way to determine (or recover its collation) how it should compare to others? For example calling:

```
SELECT equalsInJsUDF(COLLATE("hello", "und:ci"), "HELLO")
```

vs.

```
SELECT equalsInJsUDF("hello", "HELLO")
```

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements a bit more? Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/collation-concepts) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew -- I just mean `COLLATE("hello", "und:ci") = "Hello"` will be true, though `"hello" = "Hello"` will be false. So, if I pass `"hello"` to a Javascript UDF, is there a way I can know if it should compare equally to `"Hello"` or not?

Comment: Did you go through the link I shared in the above comment? Is that helpful?

Comment: @kiranmathew yes thanks for sharing but no I didn't find that helpful as to how to recover collation in a udf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use collation on a UDF according to [BigQuery Collation docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/collation-concepts):

> User-defined functions (UDFs) can't take collated arguments.
>
> ````
> CREATE FUNCTION tmp_dataset.my_udf(x STRING) AS (x);
> SELECT tmp_dataset.my_udf(col_ci)
> FROM shared_dataset.table_collation_simple;
> -- User error:
> -- "Collation is not allowed on argument x ('und:ci').
> -- Use COLLATE(arg, '') to remove collation at [1:8]"```
> ````

I suppose a workaround could be to use a predicate and see if `UPPER(stringVal) = LOWER(stringVal)`. However, that only addresses whether that collation affects equality the current string in question, and something like the following wouldn't indicate whether it has a collation or not:

```
SELECT 
  UPPER(val)=LOWER(val) AS acts_like_ci_collation
FROM
  UNNEST(['123']) as val
```